# How to use my home internet from other country so that I can browse country-restricted websites?

Tags: networking, router, vpn, internet

I need to browse websites when I travel to other countries.
Sometimes local web traffic policies may restrict the navigation of some IP.

I have a wired-line internet connection in my house. Its router's WAN IP local address is private (10.x.x.x) and dynamically assigned by the ISP.

What should I do to access my home's internet from other countries so that I can browse any website without restrictions?
If the solution will require a PC in my home, how can I use wake/sleep on LAN to save money from the electric bill?

A public VPN is not a preferred solution and the traffic should be routed to my home's network.

Comment: Shortest answer: VPN - not necessarily a public one. You can look at your home router's features and see if it has a VPN server. You VPN to this and you're on your home network. Done.

Comment: Sort answer: [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) :) ...but browsing will be not simple or fast as the _shortest answer_.

Comment: Dark answer: [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/docs/hidden-services.html.en)... it should be  a prototype of _"oversized"_ answer. @BigChris: I almost prefer when our commentswere _shorter_ :)

Comment: @BigChris "router's WAN IP address is private (10.x.x.x) and dynamically assigned by ISP" - How can you vpn to a router with a private WAN IP address?

Comment: @DavidPostill - they'll be a public IP of some sort, at least... Unless I've missed something crazy?

Comment: @BigChris My guess is he's in an apartment block, where each apartment has it's own router. Quite common in Europe where ISP's wire up whole estates of apartment blocks that way. Everybody is on the same big LAN. His "wire lan" comes from an ISP router somewhere else (could be in the same building). So effectively double NAT where he doesn't have control of the next router along.

Comment: Lame. Lol. A potential solution (if not to proxy) woule be a remote desktop solution such as LogMeIn or TeamViewer... Not many options that don't involve purchasing external services.

Comment: If you have a laptop with a modem, you can call a dial-up number in the United States. If you have a landline, you can set one up yourself and call into that from your computer, no matter where you are in the world. You don't even need an Internet connection from wherever you are. Not necessarily cheap or fast, but extremely easy and guaranteed to work no matter what. This is still very common in many Asian countries to get around Internet filtering. They can't filter audio coming through the phone lines so this gets around that.

Comment: I believe that this question deserves to remain open: having been visited 7,088 times tells us that it is an interesting topic... Answer rewritten in the light of the interest shown by the number of visits counted in 3.75 years.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access a website that is blocked from your country – you can use a Tor Browser.

By default, the Tor Browser picks random exit nodes from any country, but it can be configured to use the exit nodes with IP addresses from a particular country only.

To use an exit node from a particular country, find your Tor Browser installation folder and navigate to:

```
Browser -> TorBrowser -> Data -> Tor
```

Open the file torrc with a text editor.

Add the following line to make the Tor Browser use exit nodes from specified country only, e.g. from the United States:

```
ExitNodes {us}
```

You can also specify a list of countries whose IP addresses should be used as an exit point:

```
ExitNodes {kr},{ru},{sy},{cn}
```

Save modifications and restart the Tor Browser.

The same way you can specify which countries should be used as an entry point or blacklist the nodes located in specified countries.

Use entry nodes with IP addresses from specified countries only:

```
EntryNodes {country_code},{country_code},...
```

Never use nodes from these countries, when building a circuit:

```
ExcludeNodes {country_code},{country_code},...
StrictNodes 1
```

Never use nodes from these countries when picking an exit (nodes listed in ExcludeNodes are automatically in this list):

```
ExcludeExitNodes {country_code},{country_code},...
StrictNodes 1
```

StrictNodes: To really exclude some nodes – you must enable StrictNodes, otherwise the Tor Browser still may use the excluded nodes if it decides that it will be necessary.

you can change your tor ip on linux with flowing command

```
killall -HUP tor
```

also you can redirect all your tcp traffic to TOR for other none web applications with iptables

Comment: Meanwhile this can be a fast and good solution, IMHO it should be only the __last resort__. Indeed, _the Tor software protects you by bouncing your communications around __a distributed network of relays run by volunteers all around the world__._ This means that you will share and distribute packages of others, without knowing what is inside and, because of this _"unknown contenent"_, risking more serious consequences. Connecting with your own home network you risk `~` nothing. Moreover the OP stated "the traffic  _should be routed to my home's network_"... BTW welcome on SuperUser.

Comment: thanks haster. but if you fallow richard stallman, he highly recommended  to using tor and never talked about any risk on tor network, https://stallman.org/stallman-computing.html

Comment: You're welcome. The one you gave is an interesting page, and moreover an outstanding reference, but meanwhile `he` (that is __HE__, with his knowledge and experience) uses TOR on a browser explicitly able to _"block tracking tags and most fingerprinting methods"_, avoiding to use at all any google services, starting from US or other countries __where it is not forbidden__... on the other side a _normal user_, having less experience and knowledge, may unawares incur in risks. BTW even `he` didn't say that there are no risks... Note: with some answers you may finish in a grey muddy area.`:-/`

Comment: My friend hastur, using tor don't need much knowledge and experience, i have searched a lot in these days after your comment, i didn't find any security risk, and you can use TOR and google services together, all you need to do is to pass one or two CAPTCHA , and i am pretty sure many people in US and other country use TOR including `HE  ;-)` , if you have any document about TOR security risks please share with us. Thank you Hastur.

Comment: I agree...but we were NOT speaking about US or EU... we were speaking of countries where there are IP blocks `:-/`. Moreover you may well understand that if it is forbidden by the law of the country in which you are, you can finish in _a trap_ (you have not to use so much imagination to think how to set it up once you have the control of the internet provider)...and I can imagine they can charge you of the responsibility of what is on your computer, even if encrypted and you are unawares, just because it is forbidden to use it... If not needed (as for the OP) you can use an alternative way...

Answer (score -1):

#### Quick

- Even if not your *"preferred solution"*, to chose a **VPN provider** with the possibility to switch the *exit point* (country of the server), may be the proper solution when you travel a lot and you have different set of rules from different places.
- You can use a **[proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) server** and set your browser preferences.  Good: it will affect only that browser. Minus: if the proxy server is overloaded it will be really slow to browse.

  - Take one available for free or for payment and the traffic you will generate with your browser will seems to come from the Proxy server country.
  - Install a proxy plug-in for your browser e.g. [foxyproxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/foxyproxy-standard/)...
  - Install a proxy server on your home computer (see below); this case does have not the bottleneck of the server overloading, but in some countries of the uploading bandwidth of your home network. Often providers are generous with the download bandwidth but limited for the upload one.
- [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/docs/hidden-services.html.en) The Hidden Service Protocol, or similar; maybe too much for your purpose.

#### Home solution

1. If you have a **router** that allows you to create a local **VPN** and to use the **Dynamic DNS technology**, [DDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS#DDNS_for_Internet_access_devices) ,
   you will both save money from the electric bill and (you will) have the possibility to browse as if you were at home. No need to use your home computer. You make be part of your local VPN with your laptop, and you will find the external IP of your router via DDNS. Eg via providers as [noip](https://www.noip.com/).

   > **Dynamic DNS** providers offer a software client program that automates the discovery and registration of the client system's public IP addresses. The client program is executed on a computer or device in the private network. It connects to the DDNS provider's systems with a unique login name; the provider uses the name to link the discovered public IP address of the home network with a hostname in the domain name system...

   You may need to modify the firewall rules on the router and to check if your local provider allows it.
2. In case the **router may use DDNS** but not create a VPN, you can still save money from the electric bill **enabling `WoL`** on your home computer. You find the IP via DDNS and you can *wakeup* the computer when needed, then you can put it again to sleep (freeze, turn off, whatever).

   > Wake-on-LAN (WoL) is a network standard that allows a computer to be turned on remotely, whether it's hibernating, sleeping, or even completely powered off
3. If not, you may still save some money from the electric bill if you program your home computer to **turn on automatically** every day at a certain times (from **bios**) and **switch off** at other defined times (from the operating system, so you can interrupt it if needed). On the home computer you can install *"something"* that allows you to connect to it, then use it from remote.

   ***About something***: it can be a DDNS client, or [noip](https://www.noip.com/) to find the IP,  something like [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/) or [nomachine](https://www.nomachine.com/) or [remote desktop connection](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17463/windows-7-connect-to-another-computer-remote-desktop-connection). Note that all the files you will download will be downloaded on the remote machine (the home computer) and then you have to move them after to the laptop.

   You can also set up a [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) server on the home computer,and set your laptop browser preferences with its coordinates so that all the traffic will be re-routed via your home computer and communicate the new dynamic IP with something like [noip](https://www.noip.com/) or [DDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS#DDNS_for_Internet_access_devices). In this case when you download something you will download it directly on your laptop.

Comment: Yes, VPN is the option I am thinking of also, but I am not sure if it will work if router's WAN IP address is private and dynamic since my ISP is implementing Carrier Grade NAT (CGN). Additionally, I have an Asus RT-N16 flashed with DD-WRT. For the option of remoting computer access like nomachine, MS remote desktop, LogmeIn & Teamviewer, I see a problem there because the PC in my house (installed with that application mentioned) should be on for a long time even I do not need it.

Comment: The way I see is to have a router inside your house able to _communicate somehow_ the dynamic IP (something like _noip_) each time your provider change it (if you have an ADSL on telephone cable should be enough your neighbouring washing machine to decrease the Noise/Signal ratio force new ISP/IP connection). Moreover the router should be programmable to forward, maybe only a specific port (better an uncommon one), to your home computer that have to be able to Wake-on-LAN (WoL). BTW, you can have a VPN almost in each country with no need to have it in your own home, but often you have to pay.